# One to one relationship error on can't alter table when run artisan command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've multiple packages and users can only have one package at a time, not multiple. So, I've created one to one relationship and added a foreign key in my users table.

Here's the relevant users table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('role');
        $table->unsignedInteger('package_id');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->nullableTimestamps();

        $table->foreign('package_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('packages');
    });
}
```

And here's the packages table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('packages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('space');
        $table->string('space_type');
        $table->string('trial')->nullable();
        $table->string('trial_period')->nullable();
        $table->string('password_protected_links')->nullable();
        $table->nullableTimestamps();
    });
}
```

However, when I ran `php artisan migrate:refresh` than it appeared the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'clouder.#sql-834_1
  4' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint users_package_id_f
  oreign foreign key (`package_id`) references `packages` (`id`))

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'clouder.#sql-834_1
  4' (errno: 150)
```

However, I believe I've created the foreign key correctly. Is there anything else that I've made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by myself now. The issue I was experiencing is caused by the order of the migration. The `create_users_table` migration comes with `Laravel 5.2` out of the box as such when I've created new migrations `create_packages_table` the order of the `create_users_table` migration on the first and it was loading before the `create_packages_table`. As such when the query trying to create the `foreign` key it can't find the column on the `packages` table. So, simply renaming the `create_users_table` date to ensure it loads after the `create_packages_table` fixed the issue.

I hope someone may find it helpful in some days.